# Jupyter Hub: Fatal error in launcher, ... The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, installation, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html
I was following this guide to install jupyterhub on my computer, but after I finished install with conda

`conda install -c conda-forge jupyterhub  # installs jupyterhub and proxy`

`conda install notebook  # needed if running the notebook servers locally`

I installed on Git Bash CLI in Visual Studio Code IDE, my jupyter notebook works normally. Python was installed together with anaconda:

python 3.7.6
conda 4.8.3
jupyter core     : 4.6.1

jupyter-notebook : 6.0.3

qtconsole        : 4.6.0

ipython          : 7.12.0

ipykernel        : 5.1.4

jupyter client   : 5.3.4

jupyter lab      : 1.2.6

nbconvert        : 5.6.1

ipywidgets       : 7.5.1

nbformat         : 5.0.4
traitlets        : 4.3.3

**Error message when I tried to run**

`jupyterhub -h`

on terminal,

Jupyter Hub: Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using "<python.exe path>" "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyterhub.exe" -h': The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 1):

I had jupyter and jupyterlab installed with these commands with my virtual environment running on my pycharm terminal:

```
pip install jupyter

pip install jupyterlab
```

Then I was able to run jupyter lab with the following command:

```
jupyter-lab.exe
```